# Security of remote management through MMC and other microsoft tools

Tags: security, remote-access, windows

When you connect to a server through an MMC console on a local computer (dsa.msc for example), what ports does the connection occur on?

Is there any kind of protection from a rogue station hijaking the connection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I use Computer Management and connect to another computer, it's using microsoft-ds, which is port 445. Since there's a *lot* of traffic in a Microsoft network traveling over 445, I'm pretty certain that they do good things to prevent it being "hijacked" - whatever you mean by that. Do you mean MiTM attacks?

In most AD domains, authentication is handled by Kerberos, so a "rogue station" doesn't have the tickets that your session has. If you don't know much about Kerberos in AD, you'll definitely want to read up on it.